# Implement a secure login mechansim in Windows presentation foundation (WPF) application

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication

I created a small WPF application that does some operations. I would like to distribute this application to some people, but I want it to be accessible only by the authorized people. I don't really need a registering mechanism.

Because the application is quite small and will be delivered as an EXE file, I don't think that having a database would be an efficient idea.

I was thinking of having a file within the application that contain the credentials of the authorized people, but as far as I know, WPF applications can be easily reversed engineered. I turned my thinking into having the application contact a server to authorize the person or something, but wasn't sure whether it is a good choice or not.

Can you please suggest or throw at me some readings or best practices to study, because whenever I search about this topic I get an example of implementing the UI (which is something i know how to do) and not the login mechanism.

Comment: If your program does not use any resources from server - contacting server to validate credentials won't help (much). Person might modify your application to just ignore login check completely, without much work. Still it's a bit better than storing credentials right in application itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design Guidelines for Rich Client Applications by MSDN

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ee658087.aspx

> Read Security Considerations, Data Handling Considerations and Data
>   Access

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to reverse any .Net app , So the point of having an authentication system  is for dealing with Noobs and people who do not know about reverse programming , you can use authentication system using Cpu Id for example witch i use , but any way like i said any .Net is reversible .
I will shier my authentication logic with you:

```
 public static string GetId( )
    {
        string cpuInfo = string.Empty;
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances( );

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            if (cpuInfo == "")
            {
                //Get only the first CPU's ID
                cpuInfo = mo.Properties["processorID"].Value.ToString( );
                break;
            }
        }
        return cpuInfo;
    }
```

After you have cpu id do some encryption

```
Public static string Encrypt(string CpuId)
{ // do some encryption
    retuen encryptionCpuId;
}
```

after that in your UI create a dialog window show the user his cpuID and he will send it to you, after that you will encrypt user's cpuID and give him his activation Key , to do that you must create an other project for generate encryption , And in your App (That you want to publish) check :

```
if(Key== Encrypt(GetId()) {// Welcome }
else {Environment.Exit(0); }
```

So every user have his own Key.

After all this you must know that any one can reflect your code and crack this mechanism.